# How to access the values only in flutter map

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   "turf_amenities": {
                "turf_washroom": true,
                "turf_water": true,
                "turf_dressing": false,
                "turf_parking": true,
                "turf_gallery": true,
                "turf_cafeteria": true
            },
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the bool list like

```dart
 final bools = data["turf_amenities"]?.values.toList(); 
 print(bools);
```

```dart
final data = {
  "turf_amenities": {
    "turf_washroom": true,
    "turf_water": true,
    "turf_dressing": false,
    "turf_parking": true,
    "turf_gallery": true,
    "turf_cafeteria": true
  },
};
final values = data.values.toList();
print(
    values); //[{turf_washroom: true, turf_water: true, turf_dressing: false, turf_parking: true, turf_gallery: true, turf_cafeteria: true}]
final bools = data["turf_amenities"]?.values.toList();
print(bools); //[true, true, false, true, true, true]
```